# How to make the card fixed for entire container?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a problem with the code shown below. I want it to be fixed, therefore filling the height and the width, eliminating the scrollbar if possible.

Here is code sample:

```html
<template>
  <div class="mt-10 pt-10">
    <v-container fluid ma-0 pa-0 fill-height>
      <v-layout row wrap class="ma-0 pa-0">
        <v-flex class="xl6 md6 sm6 xs12 pa-0" absolute fixed>
          <v-card height="900" class="ma-0 pa-0" id="rounded-card">
            <v-img
                src="img.jpg"
                height="100%"/>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex class="xl6 md6 sm6 xs12 pa-0" absolute fixed>
          <v-card class="ma-0 pa-0 elevation-5" height="900">
            <item_att/>
            <v-divider/>
            <item_pro/>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want my website to have similar layout to this page: https://nephos.cssninja.io/product.html

Here's my sample page: https://thestackoverflow.netlify.com/single

Comment: I accessed your site page and got the error that page not found :(

Comment: Yeah me too... Could you also share the rest of your component/page?

Comment: [link](https://thestackoverflow.netlify.com/single) sorry here the link.

Comment: @AmirulAsyrafMohamedAzam, your page however looks completely different now. What exactly can we help you with?

Comment: actually i want to make it similar to sample website given the structure but it appear scrollbar instead of fixed to entire screen.